# Практика для изучения Java?

Tags: java

Неоднократно был задан данный вопрос, исследуя его я сделал очевидные выводы :

1. Практика и ещё раз практика 2. Курсы при компании.

Но где найти ту же практику ? ( делал пару заданий по исходникам с описанием аля https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/3.29.php , потом переделывал по другому).

Вопрос в следующем, может кто-то поделиться аналогичными ресурсами как я указал выше(необязательно ру) или же протоптанным саксес стори (опять же практика интересует, можно и не только о ней^ ).

В любом случае буду действительно признателен тем, кто отзовется и наткнувшись не пролистает плюнув!

P. S. Интересует как core (т.к на данный момент на нем), так и не только.

Comment: Знаю только платный курс

Comment: [Тут](https://juja.com.ua/)
периодически можно поучаствовать в различных проектах и записать этот опыт в свое резюме.

Comment: Немного не понял, что вы хотите, java или .net/.netcore. Для java имхо лучшая практика - создание приложений под android. Лучше всего - реализовывать свои идеи

Comment: ставишь перед собой посильную задачу и выполняешь ее (напр. написать записную книжку, файловый менеджер и тп.)

Comment: Если нужны задачи для решения, то на javaRush их вагон. Сам в свое время пользовался.

Comment: @Александр java, просто скинул для примера. Так и решил в итоге.Спасибо

Comment: @pavlofff так и будем ) спасибо

Comment: @Maxim много слышал отзывов разносторонних, думаю вот глянуть сейчас. Хотя все же думаю, выдумывать => писать

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець спасибо за линк, действительно вижу что open source свой берут, да и проект. Но решил уже чуть другим путём.

Comment: @Erick Dunstov там довольно муторно писать код на самых начальных этапах в браузере, что многих отторгает, но довольно быстро открывается плагин для idea.